# installing f# 3 windows xp using mono

Tags: f#, mono, xbuild

I'm trying install f# 3.0 from source code https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp using mono 3 instead .net tools because I've net 4.0 and  I would need a version >=4.5 (only available for windows vista and windows 8)

the problems become when I try build fsharp-proto-build.proj..I get this:

```
MSBUILD : warning MSB4056: Se debe llamar al motor de MSBuild en Singlethread-Apartment. El modelo de subprocesos actual es '"MTA".
basically it's saying than I need change the msbuild engine to singlethread instead mta...I can't found how do this...
```

when I try build fsharp-library-build.proj I get this:

```
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
warning MSB3257: La referencia principal "C:\fsh\fsharp\lib\debug\4.0\FSharp.Core.dll" no se pudo resolver porque su versión es superior "4.3.0.0" a la existente en la versión de .NET Framework de destino actual. La que se encuentra en la versión de .NET Framework de destino actual es "4.0.0.0".

************************************************************************************
I can't understand why is referencing to net framework when I'm using xbuild with mono 3





C:\fsh\fsharp\src\fsharp\FSharp.Data.TypeProviders\TypeProviderEmit.fs(25,49): error FS0039: The type 'TypeProviderEditorHideMethodsAttribute' is not defined

C:\fsh\fsharp\src\fsharp\FSharp.Data.TypeProviders\TypeProviderEmit.fs(25,42): error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints

C:\fsh\fsharp\src\fsharp\FSharp.Data.TypeProviders\TypeProviderEmit.fs(34,49): error FS0039: The type 'TypeProviderXmlDocAttribute' is not defined

........

2 warning(s)

57 Errors
```

please help I'm not familiar with .net or mono tools...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should launch Mono command prompt from start menu after installing Mono 3.0, and then execute

xbuild *the parameters*

Otherwise, xbuild is using Microsoft .NET Framework as host.

It is highly recommended to use MSBuild to build F#, and that's what they say on their README (that readme file is not very accurate for Windows case, which I might spare some time on it this weekend),

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp

As you are using Windows XP, please attempt to build a clean box, without installing Microsoft .NET Framework, and then play with Mono and F#. That should save you some time, as you don't need to fight against both.

Edited: Currently neither Mono 2.10.9 nor 3.0.3 can compile fsharp master on Windows. Will investigate further to see how to get it compiled.

Comment: thanks so much Lex, actually you're right, I don't know much about mono...I've followed your steps and running inside the mono command prompt and now I've an OutofMemoryException...I must fix this now...thanks...

Comment: @user1050817, that should be another problem. I only have time this weekend to further investigate on this issue. Hope you can wait till then.

Comment: hi lex..well I did the installation but now I found than monodevelop bindings for f# in windows doesn't works...so...I stop trying :S ...